# corona sdk - collision detection on object that changes size

Tags: iphone, lua, coronasdk

Hey I'm wondering how to check for collision on an object that grows each time it hits a certain object. I can get it to grow and recognize collision, but as the object grows, the collision hit box remains the same small size.

I'm using physics bodies and the collision event.

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an object to physics, you cant resize it in a later time. ( You can resize the image but not the physics object itself ) To succeed that, you should remove the previous object, resize the image/object and the readd to physics. Thats the only way. If you share your code block, I can help better.